Ring where all elements are potent
An element $a$ of a ring $R$ is said to be a potent element if there exists a positive integer $n\ge 2$ such that $a^n=a$. It is obvious that all idempotent elements are potent elements but converse is not true. My question is : like we have a Boolean ring where each element is idempotent. Is there any ring where all elements are potent? Obviously all Boolean rings satisfies this condition but we have to find non-trivial example. Similar to these rings we have quasi-clean rings in which every element is a sum of a potent element and a unit. We also have tripotent rings if all its elements are tripotent. But I am finding something more general.

These are the subject of a famous theorem of Jacobson. Following Martin Brandenburg let's call a ring $R$ such that $x^n = x$ for every $x$ an $n$-ring. Jacobson showed that such a ring is necessarily commutative, so let's only discuss the commutative case from here. From the definition it's clear that

$n$-rings are reduced, and
quotients of $n$-rings are $n$-rings.

So an $n$-ring $R$ embeds into the product $\prod_P R/P$ of quotients by its prime ideals $P$, and the quotients $R/P$ are integral domains which are also $n$-rings. So every element of $R/P$ satisfies $x^n = x$. Since $R/P$ is an integral domain this means it has at most $n$ elements, hence is finite. If $x \neq 0$ then $x^{n-1} = 1$, so $R/P$ is a finite field. (This means every prime ideal of $R$ is maximal, so $R$ is von Neumann regular, which also follows from directly from the definition.)
In a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ the nonzero elements are a cyclic group of order $q - 1$; since the nonzero elements of $R/P$ must also have order dividing $n - 1$, it follows that $R/P \cong \mathbb{F}_q$ is an $n$-ring iff $q - 1 \mid n - 1$. The conclusion is:

Theorem: A commutative ring $R$ is an $n$-ring $R$ iff it's a subdirect product of finite fields $\mathbb{F}_q$ with $q - 1 \mid n - 1$.

This is a direct generalization of the Boolean case $n = 2$ where the conclusion is that $R$ is a subdirect product of copies of $\mathbb{F}_2$. For example we can take $q$ any prime power such that $q - 1 \mid n -1$ and $X$ any Stone space and construct the ring of continuous functions $X \to \mathbb{F}_q$ which will be an example; this gives a contravariant equivalence of categories between Stone spaces and $\mathbb{F}_q$-algebras which are also $q$-rings, generalizing Stone's representation theorem which is the case $q = 2$.
A corollary of the theorem is that an $n$-ring has characteristic $\prod p$ where $p$ runs over all primes s.t. $p - 1 \mid n-1$. The Chinese remainder theorem then implies that an $n$-ring canonically decomposes as a product of rings of characteristic $p$ for all primes $p$ satisfying this condition, so the classification reduces to the characteristic $p$ case.
Here's a little table of what prime powers $q$ satisfy $q - 1 \mid n - 1$ for the first few values of $n$.



$n$
$q$




$2$
$2$


$3$
$2, 3$


$4$
$2, 4$


$5$
$2, 3, 5$


$6$
$2$


$7$
$2, 3, 4, 7$


$8$
$2, 8$


$9$
$2, 3, 5, 9$


$10$
$2, 4$



This table implies some fun facts; for example, that every $6$-ring is a $2$-ring (so a Boolean ring) and that every $10$-ring is a $4$-ring. More details and examples can be found in Martin's very nice linked paper.
Edit: Okay, skimming more through Martin's paper confirmed my guess: there's a precise generalization of Stone's representation theorem available here. Namely, we can reduce to the case of prime characteristic $p$ and classify $n$-rings of characteristic $p$ via Galois descent; after extending scalars to $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ for a suitable $k$ we get a Stone space $X$ together with a continuous action of $\mathbb{Z}/k$, and our original $n$-ring is the ring of $\mathbb{Z}/k$-equivariant continuous maps $X \to \mathbb{F}_{p^k}$.

What about rings where the value of $n$ varies according to the element?  For example, I'd think $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ would be an example of such a ring which is not an $n$-ring for any $n$.

@Daniel: we could consider this case too, I just had less to say about it. I think such a ring is a filtered colimit of $n$-rings. (This isn't entirely clear, we'd need to show the value of $n$ is bounded on any finitely generated subring.)
